# Laravel Convert Raw Query Containing 'as' Keyword to Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this raw query:

```sql
SELECT business_id, count(*) as how_many from dbname.gateway_transactions WHERE DATE(created_at) = '2020-02-02' group by business_id order by how_many desc limit 5
```

And this is the result:

[image]

I want to have the result of this query (the content of the image), as an array. How can I do this?

I have used this:

```php
$a = GatewayTransaction::selectRaw("SELECT business_id, count(*) as how_many from dbname.gateway_transactions WHERE DATE(created_at) = '2020-02-02' group by business_id order by how_many desc limit 5");
```

But not able to get what I need. I need such an array just like the image above:

```php
[
51  => 725,
176 => 405,
229 => 264,
98  => 109,
136 => 92
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Eloquent builder like this:

```php
$a = GatewayTransaction::selectRaw('business_id, count(*) as how_many')
                       ->whereDate('created_at', '2020-02-02')
                       ->groupBy('business_id')
                       ->orderBy('how_many', 'desc')
                       ->take(5)
                       ->get();
```

Comment: But how can I convert it as an array. `toArray()` helper does not work here.

Comment: You need to add `toArray();` after the query. `->take(5)->get()->toArray();`

Comment: @MajidAlaeinia after `get()` it will return collection, you can use `toarray()`